# Find first level pages using query

Tags: aem

I want to fetch all the pages below the current path using query, as i need to sort them also so using the query. I am using below criteria which is giving me the pages below hierarchy but also goes deep till it contains child.

```
        path=/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar
        type=cq:Page
        orderby=@jcr:content/cq:lastModified
```

I show be below result like :

```
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/newsletter  (crxde,  html,  json)
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/sitemap  (crxde,  html,  json)
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account  (crxde,  html,  json)
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account/register  (crxde,  html,  json)
/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account/register/thank_you  (crxde,  html,  json)
```

As in Account page i dont need the sub pages in result set. Please provide any criteria that fit into such type of query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **flat** property of the [PathPredicateEvaluator](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PathPredicateEvaluator.html)

The sample query would be

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar
path.flat=true
orderby=@jcr:content/cq:lastModified
orderby.sort=desc
```

It would translate to the following XPath query

```
/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/element(*, cq:Page)
order by jcr:content/@cq:lastModified descending
```

To know more about the various properties available, refer the implementing classes of [PredicateEvaluator](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PredicateEvaluator.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an XPath query, you can simply remove the double forward slash. E.g. using the QueryBuilder debugger, your predicates give an XPath of `/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar//element(*, cq:Page)`

If you change this to:

`/jcr:root/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/element(*, cq:Page)`

i.e. removing the second forward slash immediately before "element", it will just search direct children. You can preview this on the CRX explorer:

```
http://localhost:4502/crx/explorer/ui/search.jsp?Path=&Query=%2fjcr%3aroot%2fcontent%2fgeometrixx%2fen%2ftoolbar%2felement(*%2c%20cq%3aPage)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using http://localhost:8502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html, here i am adding criteria. So in case you have an idea about what other criteria that i can add please tell in querybuilder

Comment: Also i want the pages in sorted order. Or Can you provide the sql query for same that where pages with fetch orderBy lastModifiedDate.